I have two select boxes bound in vue to a model (v-model) both are bound to different attributes of the same object. One works as expected, one doesnt
Here is the first select:
<select :disabled="disabled" class="form-control" id="users" ref="users" @change="setUser()"
                  v-model="dAppt.User" >
            <option disabled selected value="{}">Choose an Employee</option>
            <option v-for="(u,idx) in users" :key="u" :id="idx" :value="u"   >{{ u.getFullName() }}</option>
          </select>

Here is the second:
<select :disabled="disabled" class="form-control" id="job" ref="job" v-model="dAppt.job"
                  :change="setDurations">
            <option disabled selected value="{}">{{ jobMessage }}</option>

            <option v-for="(j,idx) in userJobs" :key="j" :id="userJobs[idx][0]"
                    :value="getJobName(userJobs[idx][0])">{{ getJobName(userJobs[idx][0]) }}
            </option>
          </select>

To try to diagnose this I log the appointment (this.dAppt) in the updated hook. It holds the expected values. Note the job name is a simple string while the user is another object in the appointment object.
As a work around I tried a variety of ways to set the selected value. Here is that code
for(let idx =0;idx < this.users.length;idx++){
    if(this.users[idx].id.trim() === this.dAppt.User.id.trim()){
      console.log("found one")
      console.log(this.dAppt.User.getFullName())
      if(this.$refs.users !== null) {
        //this.$refs.users.selectedIndex = idx + 1
        //this.$refs.users.options.selectedIndex = idx +1
        this.$refs.users.value = this.dAppt.User
      }


      break;
    }
  }

The one that works is the job(s) select (simple string) and the one that doesn't it the user(s) select (an object).
Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

I'd say one issue is in here <option v-for="(u,idx) in users" :key="u" :id="idx" :value="u"> - an <option> value is a string - clearly you've set it as an Object - I dare say :key is not expecting an object either ... perhaps use u.id for key and value - see how that helps

Thanks for your interest, but changing it did not fix the issue.

I changed the value to the user.id as suggested and then changed v-model from the user of the appointment to the user.id of the appointment. All works now. Thanks for the help.
